# Is FreeRaduis for Windows still available?

Tags: freeradius

Is FreeRaduis for Windows still available ?

I have followed links from several sites, but all seem to be dead
or lead nowhere.
The download page does not seem to offer the Windows version.

Answer (score 0):

There has *never* been any official Windows version of FreeRADIUS.

Many years ago someone (unknown) provided binaries of FreeRADIUS version 1 for Windows, but with no source provided or build instructions there was no way to trust it. Even if this was still available it's completely obsolete. Thankfully that web site no longer exists.

Either run version 3 in Linux for real, or use the Windows Linux subsystem to run it if you really have to use that OS. I would recommend building a real Linux VM which will be the most tested and supportable solution - FreeRADIUS development is done on Linux and macOS.